# tmuxinator: Escape pipe character

Tags: pipe, tmuxinator

I encountered the following problem:
I can't escape the pipe sign in the tmuxinator config.

tmuxinator does not generate the output for the two commands for the `Tests` window. Everything else works like expected.

I tried to escape the pipe sign `|` with a backslash `\` and tried to wrap the string in single- and double quotes.

I checked the commands which will be executed with `tmuxinator debug`

Here is my tmuxinator config file:

```
name: PyCIn
root: /srv/PyCIn/
pre_window:
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - clear
windows:
  - Git: # placeholder
  - Run:
    - clear
    - TRAVIS=true GH_TOKEN=asdf python -m pycin inspect
  - Tests:
    layout: main-horizontal
    panes:
    - ag -l | entr -c make pep8
    - ag -l | entr -c make tests-coverage
```

Does any1 have a hint for me? :)

For the record:

`ag` searches all files with the given text (here none, so list all files)

`entr` executes the given command when any of the file changes

Here is the complete file as [gist](https://gist.github.com/YannickFricke/a69689a596bf2b2c9425ac7107f686f7). Copy pasted from the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, pipes work as expected in Yaml/Tmuxinator, which makes me think this is a Yaml indentation issue. After tweaking the indentation in your config file, `ag -l` pipes its output as expected.

```
# /home/yfr/.config/tmuxinator/PyCIn.yml

name: PyCIn
# root: /srv/PyCIn/
pre_window:
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - clear
windows:
  - Git: # placeholder
  - Run:
      - clear
      - TRAVIS=true GH_TOKEN=asdf python -m pycin inspect
  - Tests:
      layout: main-horizontal
      panes:
        #- ag -l | entr -c make pep8
        #- ag -l | entr -c make tests-coverage
        - ag -l | xargs
        - ag -l | xargs
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! :)

Yeah also tried it... but still no sucess.

I added a Gist of the file to the main post.

Still can't figure out, why it doesnt work :(

Comment: @YannickFricke Your indentation (specifically, your commands) still looks out of whack. Try again with my updated answer. ([Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/k9h5A5g).)

Comment: Thank you :) Now it works :) Marked your answer as the solving one :) Merry christmas to you and your family! :)